# Gal$(X^2-X-1) ⊆ S_2$ and Gal$(X^9-X) ⊆ S_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

The question I'm trying to answer reads:

> Describe the embeddings Gal$(f) \subset S_2$ and Gal$(f) \subset S_9$ for $f = X^2 - X - 1$ and $f = X^9-X ∈ _3[X]$

but I don't know how to interpret it. Does it mean Gal$(X^2 -X-1) \subset S_2$ and Gal$(X^9-X) \subset S_9$ or also, in addition, Gal$(X^2 -X-1) \subset S_9$ and Gal$(X^9 -X) \subset S_2$? I'm completely new to Galois theory, and might lack some relevant knowledge about finite fields..

Comment: Looks like whoever asked you this question wants you to realize the Galois group of a polynomial as permutations of the roots. The quadratic has two roots, hence its Galois group is (or at least can be viewed as) a subgroup of $S_2$. The other polynomial has nine roots, so its Galois group can be seen as a subgroup of $S_9$.

Comment: Hint: Both polynomials split over $\Bbb{F}_9$.

Comment: So if I were to identify the zeros in $_9 (= \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}??)$ of both polynomials, say, $z_1, z_2$ for the first one, then I could just map the permutation $z_1 \leftrightarrow z_2$ to the cycle $(z_1 \,\, z_2) ∈ S_2$, right?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman note that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field only when $p$ is prime. The field $F_9$ of $9$ elements can be described, for example, as the splitting field of $g = X^9-X \in F_3[X]$. The existence of splitting field can be proved from the existence of algebraic closures: pick an algebraic closure and adjoint the roots of $g$ there to $F_3$. This gives a field $K$. Since $\alpha \mapsto \alpha^9$ is a field morphism in characteristic $3$, one can actually see that any $x \in K$ satisfies $x^9 = x$ and so $K$ consists exactly of the roots of $g$, having thus $9$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jyrki points out in the comments, if $f \in k[X]$ is a nonconstant separable polynomial with (distinct) roots $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in \overline{k}$, the extension $k(\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n)/k$ is Galois and a morphism

$$
\sigma : k(\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n)/k \to 
k(\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n)
/k
$$

is determined by $\sigma(\alpha_i)$ for each $i$. Note that field morphisms are injective so $\sigma(\alpha_i) \neq \sigma(\alpha_j)$ when $i\neq j$. This defines a permutation on $\{1,\dots, n\}$ via

$$
\tau_\sigma(i) = j \iff \sigma(\alpha_i) = \alpha_j
$$

and the function $\sigma \in Gal(f) \mapsto \tau_\sigma \in S_n$ is a group morphism. Moreover, it is injective: if $\tau_\sigma = 1$, then $\sigma(\alpha_i) = \alpha_i$ for all $i$ and thus $\sigma = id$.

Hence $Gal(f) \hookrightarrow S_{\deg f}$ for any $f \in k[X]$ (separable and non-constant) via the aforementioned assignment.

Comment: What I still don't understand is this: to determine whether $X^2 -X -1$ is separable, we must determine whether it has repeated roots. Using the quadratic formula, we find that its roots are $\frac{1}{2} ± \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}$. Does that mean its splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt{5})$? Does that expression even make sense? What would that field even look like?

Comment: Note that if $f = x^2 - x -1$ then $f' = 2x-1$ whose only root in $F_3$ is $2$. But $2^2 - 2 -1 = 1 \neq 0$, so $f$ and $f'$ do not share roots: hence $f$ is separable.

Comment: As for your calculation, note that $5 = 2$ mod $3$. Also $\sqrt{2}$ should mean a root of $g = X^2-2$ in an algebraic closure of $F_3$.  Since $g$ is irreducible in $F_3[X]$ (because it has degree $2$ and so roots in $F_3$), such a root $\beta$ has minimal polynomial $g$ over $F_3$, and thus $[F_3(\beta) : F_3] = 2$ which means that $F_3(\beta) = F_9$ (you can check that $\beta \in F_9$ since $\beta^9 = \beta$ and both fields have the same amount of elements).

Comment: Hence an $F_3$-basis of this field could be $\{1,\beta\}$ and so its elements are of the forma $a+b\beta$ with $a,b \in F_3$.

Comment: (also, $1/2$ here is just $2$ as $4 = 1$ mod $3$)

Comment: Great! I now think I understand the case of $f$ completely! And learned a lot from this. My suspicion is now that, as $X^9-X$ has the same splitting field, they will have the same Galois groups and we can use _the exact same embedding_ in $S_9$ as in $S_2$ (The one where id $↦ (1)$ and $(a+b\sqrt{2} ↦ a-b\sqrt{2}) ↦ (12)$)! We don't need the rest of $S_9$! However, doesn't that contradict the fact that $X^9-X$ is separable (Its derivative is $9X^8 - 1 = 0 - 1 = -1$, which has no roots)? Shouldn't it have 9 distinct roots?

Comment: The polynomial $g$ has $9$ distinct roots and so its Galois group is a subgroup of $S_9$, but it may as well be very small. Actually, one can show that $\mathsf{Gal}(F_{3^j}/F_3) \simeq Z_j$.  We know the automorpshisms are permutations of the $9$ distinct roots, but not every permutation is admissible: in fact, we have shown that there are only two valid such morphisms.

Comment: (I meant $\mathbb{Z}_j$, can't edit the comment now. For a proof: show that its Galois group is cyclic with generator the Frobenius map $\alpha \mapsto \alpha^3$.)